# Could the first byte of a stdin data stream trigger a bash command to run?

Tags: java, python, linux, bash

I have the following piped bash commands :

```
command_1 | command_2 | command_3
```

where `command_1` is waiting to generate a data stream which triggers `command_2` to start to process it and then sends the process data stream to `command_3` .

The problem is that I don't know when `command_1` would start and `command_2` could not be started earlier than the arrival of the data stream (otherwise `command_2` would fail as there would be no data to process). `command_3` is not special in this scenario.

I want to know that could `command_2` be executed inside a bash/python/java script which waits to read the first byte of a stdout data stream from `command_1` and this first byte would then trigger the start of the execution of `command_2` which needs to process this first byte together with the remaining continuous bytes of the stdin data stream (`command_2` should not skip any byte from `command_1` otherwise the result would be invalid).

Could this `command_2` logic be implemented in a script. Any idea?

Comment: Usually you'd have something that just takes input until EOF or whatever and generates output. What exactly is `command_2`?

Comment: It can be done in Java, Python, Bash, and any modern programming language. Just read the standard input descriptor until the end-of-file (i.e. end of input from the pipe) is reached.

Comment: @Iluvatar `command_2` may be `nc 192.168.1.x 3333` which connects to a remote server which expects immediate data to pass to the server (otherwise may timeout). In this case `command_3` is not necessary.

Comment: `command_2` would not fail if there was no data in the stream, it would block.

Comment: @Ruslan I could not read until EOF as the data is an endless continuous stream.

Comment: @user1129812, then read endlessly =) Or break the loop depending on specific condition, maybe asynchronously (signals etc.).

Comment: @user1129812 - Can you please give more data or example of the commands you wish to run which doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, in python, for instance, you just have to read the stdin:

```
  import sys

  for line in sys.stdin:
      if line == b'something':
          print('received', line)
```

Depending on your usecase, you may need to flush the output, so instead of print, you can do:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write(b'received {line}')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

`'received {line}'` will be passed to command_3

Comment: This seems not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some readers obviously have missed your requirement to start `command_2` not before pipe data is available, because it would timeout otherwise. It's quite easy with this script I'll call `postpone.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import select
select.select([0], [], [])
import os
import sys
os.execvp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:])
```

It just waits until input is ready, and then executes the given command. Usage e. g.:

```
command_1 | postpone.py command_2 | command_3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a bash pipeline `command_1 | command_2 | command_3`. If so I think you misunderstand the way those pipes is executed.

1. Each pipe `|` is created as an input-output buffer.
2. Each command is created while it's standard input/output is replaced with the relevant buffer end if needed.
   2.1. std-in --> command_1 --> buffer_1
   2.2. buffer_1 --> command_2 --> buffer_2
   2.3 buffer_2 --> command_3 --> std-out

At that point when `command_2` "reads" data, it will block on the `buffer_1` until data will be available there. It will end its process when it will get EOF  signal. The fact that `command_1` haven't write data yet is not a problem.